# Unable to build Apple's example project core data book

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, core-data

I opened the core data book example directly from Xcode's documentation window. The project won't build. It says the Iphone OS 4.0 is missing. Since I used Xcode 3 with SDK of iOS 4.2, I changed the build SDK to iOS4.2 (latest), but it then says:

> Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.CoreDataBooks' could not be found

If I change the code signing identity to "don't code sign", it says:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.2'

I am not sure whether the $99 developer fee is required to run the example. Would that be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leo,

Code signing error will  occur only  when you try to make device build and either dont have provisioning profile or you are giving wrong information.

Following error occurs when you provide wrong identifier, If you have provisioning profile (check in organizer of XCode, under windows menu)then you should provide its app identifier starting from com. and so on.

`Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.CoreDataBooks' could not be found`

The second error you are getting is because you are trying to build, device build without having any profile. `CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.2'`

If you want to make that application's device build you should have right provisioning profile, else you would not be able to make it.

If you only wants to run it on simulator then you can do it easily. 
On the LeftMost corner top you will fine a dropdown menu. In that you will need to select Simulator and Debug. And after that clean all targets and "Build and Run" application.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice the default (or somehow changed by me) setting is device & release. I only need to run in simulator. Thanks!